# Most common sequence of characters in a given string

Tags: sequence

Suppose I am given a string of characters. How to find the most common sequence of characters with a minimum length of `l`?

Programming language doesn't matter but it should work with a string of 1000+ at an usual Computer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to find all possible sequences and count them. That is,

```
for (each position in string) {
    length = 0;
    do {
        sequence = (string from position to position + length);
        count sequence locations in string;
        if (count is higher than max count) {
            remember sequence;
            update max count;
        }
        length++;
        if (position + length > string.length or length > sequence limit) break;
    }
}
```

It is possible that same sequences will be met in different string places so they will be counted abundantly. This is harmless but takes some extra cycles. A way to avoid that is to store found sequences and don't check those already checked. But memory requirements for long strings and long sequences may become huge.